# Self Publishing vs Mainstream Publisher

Tags: publishing, self-publishing, electronic-publishing

I am in the middle of writing my first non-fiction book and I am almost finished with designing my blog page discussing the subject I am writing about with small snippets of my writing.

I am trying to weigh-up whether to attempt publishing through a mainstream publisher or go straight for digital self publishing through Amazon Kindle.

**What are the pros and cons for each publishing route?**

Comment: this has already been discussed in the above question.

Comment: one thing I will say about that top answer though, is that a mainstream publisher doing the marketing for you and you being able to concentrate on nothing but the writing isn't true any more. Unless you have a 'super release' where the publisher puts all their marketing efforts into your book because they are confident it's going to be a bestseller (and publishers only do 1-2 super releases a year), you will be expected to market your own work and find your own readers (with the exception of them perhaps tweeting and running a few ads).